# Which function in django.contrib.auth creates the default model permissions?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-migrations

in the django documentation it says:

> These permissions will be created when you run manage.py migrate; the first time you run migrate after adding django.contrib.auth to INSTALLED_APPS, the default permissions will be created for all previously-installed models, as well as for any new models being installed at that time. Afterward, it will create default permissions for new models each time you run manage.py migrate (the function that creates permissions is connected to the post_migrate signal)

It says that the function that creates these permissions is connceted to the post_migration signal. I was wondering which function is this because I need to make the default permissions programatically in my coode.

Answer (score 2):

The post migration signal is fired from [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/contrib/auth/apps.py#L17)

```
class AuthConfig(AppConfig):
     name = 'django.contrib.auth'
     verbose_name = _("Authentication and Authorization")

     def ready(self):
         post_migrate.connect(
             create_permissions,
            dispatch_uid="django.contrib.auth.management.create_permissions"
        )
    ...
```

And the permission are created from [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py)